Default ways to compute decomposition and formation enthalpies in Siesta
I was examining the material project database and saw the thermodynamic stability section of crystalline silicon. I noticed that they compute formation and decomposition enthalpies. I wonder if there is a straightforward way to reproduce these results in Siesta.
Also, in the computations section, the total energy is reported per calculation. I tried to reproduce that result but got a very different energy result. Any ideas of what could be wrong?
SystemLabel      Si_test
NumberOfAtoms    8

NumberOfSpecies  1
%block ChemicalSpeciesLabel
    1   14  Si
%endblock ChemicalSpeciesLabel

LatticeConstant 5.44 Ang
%block LatticeParameters
  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  90.000000  90.000000  90.000000
%endblock LatticeParameters

AtomicCoordinatesFormat Fractional
%block AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
     0.125000000     0.125000000     0.125000000    1
     0.125000000     0.625000000     0.625000000    1
     0.625000000     0.625000000     0.125000000    1
     0.625000000     0.125000000     0.625000000    1
     0.875000000     0.375000000     0.375000000    1
     0.875000000     0.875000000     0.875000000    1
     0.375000000     0.375000000     0.875000000    1
     0.375000000     0.875000000     0.375000000    1
%endblock AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies

Thank you.

The data about thermodynamic stability section (in the link) is empty. To check the results, you need to run your calculations with the same parameters (k-points, thresholds, pseudo-potentials, etc.).

Hi @Camps, thank you for your answer. I double-checked and the thermodynamic info is there. Also, I know that if I want the same results I would have to run the same simulation, but regardless I would expect similar results. Not 1-2 orders of magnitude difference.
